# Compute of roots for complex quadratic polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, quadratics

The problem statement is to solve the quadratic equation $p(w) = zw^{2}+(1\color{red}+z^{2})w+z = 0 $ in $\mathbb{C}$.

For Real numbers it's easy, becouse we have $\Delta$ which works for complex version. But am have't idea how to use for complex equation.

Can you had some issue?

Comment: do you wanna solve for $z$ or $w$?

Comment: for $w$ I need compute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quadratic formula is just fine. It will tell you the two solutions for $w$ in terms of $z$ since the discriminant will have two square roots (unless it's $0$). The solutions need not be complex conjugates (as in the real case).

Comment: @Blabla You comment elsewhere that the two solutions are $w=z$ and $s = 1/z$. Only one of those is in the unit disk.

Comment: Yes, I see now :) thanks !